# <p:fileUpload> not uploading files when <p:commandButton> button is clicked

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

In my JSF 2-Primefaces application I am using  to upload a file. I need to upload this file along with the other contents in the same form when  is clicked. But this does not work.
If I use 'Simple' file upload then validating the file becomes the problem.

Any clues?

Comment: How exactly is JSP related to this? PrimeFaces does not support JSP at all. It works on Facelets only.

Comment: Can you show script? Try to use Basic FileUpload. Or you can first upload file (Single, Multiple) and then execute form.

Comment: Some code would be appreciated and would help us help you ;)